# Refresh div after loading form with jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to load a html page with a form using

```js
$('div_name').load('page_name.html');
```

However, JQuery Mobile doesn't take effect on this loaded form.

I've tried

```js
...load(..).trigger('create')
```

which didn't do the trick either.

Comment: What do you mean by `'div_name'`?

Comment: `div_name` is this class or id?

Comment: $("#div_name").load("page.html") where the div_name is the id

Comment: what re you trying to load? please post more details and relevant code.

Comment: Im trying to load a file with that starts and end with form tags  e.g. <form>    <label for="txtGroup">Group Name</label> <input type="text" id="txtGroup" /><br />
</form>